# How far apart should be fruit trees, in northern California climate (hot, dry summers -- cold, rainy winters)

Tags: trees, fruit-trees

We want to plant some fruit trees:
plum, apricot, apple, peach, fig, mandarin, cherry, nectarine

Location is zip code 95682, east of Sacramento at about 1100 ft. elevation.
Good black dirt.  Well drained.  Direct sun, of course.

Comment: The answer will depend not only on the fruit, but much more on the rootstock, which will in turn determine the size of the mature trees. Can you tell us a bit more about your plans re. tree size?

Comment: Are they dwarf, semi-dwarf, or standard-sized? However, it should be noted that if you don't prune the smaller trees, they still get pretty big. So, I'd still space most of them similarly, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember the spacing off-hand, but on about 0.0833333 acres (a third of a fourth of an acre), you should be able to comfortably fit about 7 to 10 fruit trees at the most (assuming they're mostly semi-dwarf; at least a couple could be standards). If you want anything else besides trees on the land, you'll want fewer trees.

Note that fig, apple, and orange trees can live a long time. Peach and nectarine trees are only rated for about 12 years. The apricot will probably be one of the biggest, and shadiest, even if it's a semi-dwarf.